# Writing API called from Lua - 0 or 1 based?

Tags: api, lua, conventions, indices

If you were to write an API that is called from Lua (which is 1-based, e.g. table indices start at 1), would you apply the same rule to your API?

For example, say your API had a function called GetFoo(x, y) which returned a Foo at the coordinate (x,y). Would you start your coordinate axes at (0,0) or (1,1) for the API, assuming that in the system itself (say written in C or C++ which are 0-based) these things start at (0,0) (so if you used the Lua convention you would always have to subtract 1 when retrieving numbers for these kinds of operations from the lua stack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Lua, but I would say for a coordinate system specifically (0,0) would be preferred.

For everything else, as long as you state it clearly in the documentation, by all means start indices at 1.

Comment: I agree, for the particular case of a coordinate system it makes no sense to start coordinates at (1, 1). Specifically if you intend to eventually extend your system to floating point and/or negative coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the 0 index in your table/arrays. The only inconvenience is the standard libraries use the 1-based convention. So things like table.sort, string operations, etc ... will ignore the table[0] element.